# How do I save a reference to a specific photo on iPhone for loading without picker?

Tags: iphone, save, photo

A user can select a photo from their library using the image picker - I want to remember this selection and display this picture in future without the user having to pick it. How can I reference the specific photo or is there a way I can copy the photo to my application's storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can save the selected image by converting it into NSData object and then writing it on the iphone file system under your app's document directory like this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filename = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SavedImage"];

[imageData writeToFile:filename atomically:NO];
}
```